# PixelDensity Metadata Tag QuickTime

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

Making a screen recording with QuickTime on a retina mac embeds a `com.apple.quicktime.pixeldensity` metadata tag on the video that tells QuickTime to have 2x pixel density. How can I add this tag to a different video? Googling `com.apple.quicktime.pixeldensity` yield no results which is really really weird.

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/how-does-quicktime-player-know-when-do-play-a-video-in-hidpi-retina-2x-mode

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586732/how-can-i-retain-2x-pixel-density-when-encoding-retina-screen-capture-with-ffmpe/31600506

Comment: Seems like the tag must have the value `0x30` to trigger high dpi playback in quicktime.